# XCode Storyboard Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, storyboard

I cant see the Labels, Button etc in the View or their constraints though the Labels and Button appears on the side of the storyboard. And when you run the program in the simulator you can see that they are there.
The project from my colleague who uses XCode 6.3.1 and I am using XCode 6.3.2
and he doesn't have this issue. When he updated his to to the same version I have he had the same problem; so he went back to the previous version 6.3.1.
Now the problem persisted on my device even when I removed the 6.3.2 and substitute it with 6.3.1

stackoverflow prevented me from uploading the images but I can send it by email to anyone to see the screen shots

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer but yet the labels seems to be shifted out of the view. but the Answer is: This problem occurs when one of the users design the view controller using the compact or any other dimension other than Any X Any. to fix the problem, click in any of the objects created ( label, button..etc), and go the attribute inceptor, and scroll down to the bottom and you will find a check box with the word installed. there will probably be more than one. Look for the one that is not highlighted, and highlight it. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another faster solution instead of going over each object you can deselect
Use Auto Layout
Use Size Classes

then select them again

Comment: I changed the layout from wAny hAny to wCompact hAny and it just worked perfectly.